# How to retrieve values from list: python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Summary:** I have a list

```
list = [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'elements': 'A',
            'table': 'maps/partials/a.html',
            'chart': 'maps/partials/charts/a.html',
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'elements': 'B',
            'table': 'maps/partials/census/b.html',
            'chart': 'maps/partials/charts/b.html',
        },
        {
            'id': '3',
            'elements': ('C','D','E','F'), //i believe it is wrong 
            'table': 'maps/partials/census/common.html',
            'chart': 'maps/partials/charts/common.html',
        },]
some_arr = ['E','2011','English','Total']
```

I want to compare `elements` with items in `some_arr`. 
and i am doing this to get list and compare it with some_arr.

```
for data in list:
            for i in range(len(some_arr)):
                if data['elements'] == some_arr[i]:
                    print(data['id'])
```

As you can see in `'id':3` section_title has 4 values. How do i compare elements here with some_arr.

Comment: What is `some_arr` example??

Comment: I am getting those values from `form action`(jquery). And i am collecting those values in `some_arr`(views.py).

Comment: do you want to see if any values are in some_arr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find any matches:

```
lst = [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'elements': 'A',
            'table': 'maps/partials/a.html',
            'chart': 'maps/partials/charts/a.html',
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'elements': 'B',
            'table': 'maps/partials/census/b.html',
            'chart': 'maps/partials/charts/b.html',
        },
        {
            'id': '3',
            'elements': ('C','D','E','F'),
            'table': 'maps/partials/census/common.html',
            'chart': 'maps/partials/charts/common.html',
        }]
some_arr = ['E','2011','English','Total']
st = set(some_arr)

from collections import Iterable
for d in lst:
    val = d["elements"]
    if isinstance(val, Iterable) and not isinstance(val, str):
        if any(ele in st for ele in val):
            print(d["id"])
    else:
        if val in st:
            print(d["id"])
```

Making a set of all the elements in `some_arr` will give you `O(1)` lookups, using `isinstance(val, Iterable) and not isinstance(val, str)` will catch any iterable value like a list, tuple etc.. and avoid iterating over a string which could give you false positives as `"F"` is in `"Foo"`.
[any](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any) will *short circuit* on the first match so if you actually want to print id for every match then use a  for loop. Lastly if you are using python2 use `basestring` instead of `str`.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm with little changes.

Comment: No worries,  do you actually want to see if there is any match or do you want to check all elements regardless?

Comment: No thank you I just want to see any match regardless. btw i am using python3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set.intersection` to get the intersection between them but before you need to check that if it's a tuple then use `intersection`.

Also in the first case you can use `in` to check the membership to check if `data['elememnt']` in in `some_arr` then print `data['id']`:

```
for data in list:
        d=data['elements']
        if isinstance(d,tuple):
           if set(d).intersection(some_arr):
                print(data['id'])
        if d in some_arr:
              print(data['id'])
```